# Java : How to get a Request object for your AWS Lambda event from API Gateway?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is there any way to get the values in the lambda function which is in **JAVA**?
I can see that there is **event.params** in nodejs but I can't figure out a similar way in Java.

I can use this in API Gateway Content-Type as,

```
{
   "name": "$input.params('name')"
}
```

But,

How can we get this input in AWS Lambda in **Java**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html) for Lambda function handlers in Java (emphasis mine):

> The general syntax for the handler is as follows:
>
> ```
> outputType handler-name(inputType input, Context context) {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> *inputType* – The first handler parameter is the input to the handler, **which can be event data** (published by an event source) or custom input that you provide such as a string or any custom data object. In
>   order for AWS Lambda to successfully invoke this handler, the function
>   must be invoked with input data that can be serialized into the data
>   type of the input parameter.

So that would be available in your `input` parameter.

Comment: How is this serialization done?  If I provide `{"hi":"bye"}` and my Java Object is `public class Yolo { private final String hi; public Yolo(String hi) { this.hi = hi; } }` will this just work?

Comment: My question is answered here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html  - you need to use mutable Objects because Lambda instantiates and then sets.  Boo.

Answer (score 0):

Code example: Copy the snippet and implement yourself

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
 import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
 import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

 public class ClassName implements RequestStreamHandler {
 @Override
 public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, 
 Context context) throws IOException {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
     JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

     try {
         JSONObject event = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);

         //your code here. Use the jsonObject as you wish

         response.put("isBase64Encoded", false);
         response.put("statusCode", 200);
         response.put("headers", headerJson);
         response.put("body", "");
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         response.put("statusCode", int);
         response.put("exception", ex);
     }

     OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
     writer.write(response.toString());
     writer.close();
 }
}
```

For response object JSON FOrmat follow link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/